# NEW to SQL Need help finding specific duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let me start by saying this is not clean data and was not created by me, it is information gathered from another program my work uses. Basically I started with an html file, and created a csv imported it into sql server. I have 3 columns JobNumber ArchiveMedium and ArchiveCreationDate.

Example

```
JobNumber     ArchiveMedium
81609         0004026
81609         \\Datablock1\datablockstore1\
```

When I used the count(*) I have about 6000+ duplicate records showing. Is there a way for me to write a select query that will show me only duplicate records meeting the criteria in my example above.

Most of the duplicates are a job number with a corresponding number ie below..

```
JobNumber    ArchiveMedium 
81608        000396I 
81608        000396K
81608        000396H
```

I am only concerned with the duplicate JobNumber that has a ArchiveMedium number along with a \Datablock.....

Does this make sense? Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments i assume that this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT JobNumber , SUM(Col1) , SUM(Col2) 

FROM (
SELECT JobNumber , case when ArchiveMedium like '\\Datablock%' then 1 else 0 end AS Col1 , case when ArchiveMedium not like '\\Datablock%' then 1 else 0 end AS Col2
from Table_2) AS T1
GROUP BY JobNumber
HAVING SUM(Col1) > 0 AND SUM(Col2)  > 0
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That is exactly what I was talking about!!

Comment: @Chris if this is what you are looking for why not acceptibg the answer!!??

Comment: @chris you have to accept an answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site. All set.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select jobNumber
from t
group by jobNumber
having sum(case when ArchiveMedium like '\\Datablock%` then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       count(*) > 1;
```

This should return all job numbers that have at least one "datablock" record.  You can join back to the original table to get the detailed rows, if you want them.

Comment: This does find duplicate job numbers, but it doesn't differentiate whether or not ArchiveMedium has a number or "\\Datablock". I need some way of finding only the duplicate JobNumber that have a  "\\Datablock" and a number in the ArchiveMedium column. There is about 259,000 records, so it is really hard to do anything visually. Sorry if I am not making any sense.

Comment: @chris . . . What do you mean by "number" in the `AchiveMedium` column?  You question is unclear on what the format is.

Comment: ArchiveMedium is a VarChar, and ArchiveMedium consists of either numbers like 000043 or \\Datablock. I need duplicates from my JobNumber column that have both 000043 and \\Datablock in the ArchiveMedium column. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Basically if the a single JobNumber like 111111 has a record for both 000043 and \\datablock. this indicates to me that it is stored in two locations.